# Best way to handle an internal job I am interested in?

Tags: hiring-process, promotion, internal-transfer

So I've been recommended by someone very senior to my head of dept to move to another team (I work in IT), and it is an offer that interests me and is generally right for me.

I am going to discuss this with my head of dept (who is not my line manager) after the Christmas break, but I know that there will be some reasons to state that the move is not practical such as below.

I perform a lot of duties in my current position, some COMPLETELY different to my core job (I did this out of initiative and to improve service), so cover will not be possible. I am also the most experienced in the team.

Also, would my Line Manager think I am not dedicated to the current position?

This is my main concern and what I think will be the roadblock. How can this be handled?

The company does generally encourage internal applicants to roles.

What's the best way to approach this? I am looking to meet with my head of dept first and then go from there.

I work in IT and have been at the company for five years.

Comment: You say "recommended...to move" and you also say "it is an offer".  So have you actually received an offer?

Comment: I get the impression you're just thinking out loud here and don't really have a practical question that fits our site's guidelines (more on those in [help] and [tour]). Can you identify a central question? Reading between the lines, I suspect your main worry is (likely misplaced) concern over your current manager's reaction? You could [edit] your question to focus on that part of it but I'm not sure if that's the direction you want to take the question in.

Comment: I totally agree with you on this process.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should look out primarily for yourself here, and your own career mobility, rather than your current department.  It is very standard for companies to have potential for transfer within the business.  It is actually to their benefit, since it increases overall employee retention and keeps experienced workers' knowledge within the company.

Some of the concerns that you brought up are really your current manager's responsibility to take care of.  Redundancy needs to be built into process, such that if one employee leaves or is out for an extended period of time, such as illness, someone else can fill in.

If you are concerned that your Line Manager might think poorly of you, you might quietly submit your application for the position and progress through the system that way.  At this point, there is no certainty yet that you might receive an offer.  It could not hurt to obtain more information about the position in the meantime.

This sounds like you are at the top of your career potential for this position and are at the stepping point on to the next level.  I would not hesitate to take that step.

Good luck!